# Is there a method to perform this function recursively?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, recursion

I'm still relatively new to Python. Is there a way that I can perform this function recursively? I'm looking for matching pairs and excluding non-matching pairs with '+'.

```
integ = 3    #number of sequences
evenList = ['GAAGCTCG', 'AAATTT', 'CTCTAGGAC']
oddList = ['CCTCGGGA', 'GGGCCC', 'GAGTACCTG']

def matchList(evenList, oddList, integ):

        indexElement = 0
        indexList = 0
        totalIndexSeq = []
        at_List = ['AT', 'TA', 'at', 'ta']
        gc_List = ['GC', 'CG', 'gc', 'cg']
        for x in evenList:
            indexedSeq = ''
            for y in x:
                if y + oddList[indexList][indexElement] in gc_List:
                    indexedSeq += str(indexElement)
                    indexElement += 1
                elif y + oddList[indexList][indexElement] in gc_List:
                    indexedSeq += str(indexElement)
                    indexElement += 1
                elif y + oddList[indexList][indexElement] in at_List:
                    indexedSeq += str(indexElement)
                    indexElement += 1
                elif y + oddList[indexList][indexElement] in at_List:
                    indexedSeq += str(indexElement)
                    indexElement += 1
                else:
                    indexedSeq += "+"
                    indexElement += 1
            indexList += 1
            indexElement -= indexElement
            totalIndexSeq.append(indexedSeq)
        return (totalIndexSeq)
        #This returns the positions with mismatched pairs omitted by a "+"
# When you print 'totalIndexSeq'
#['0+234+6+']
#['0+234+6+', '++++++']
#['0+234+6+', '++++++', '012++5678']
```

Comment: What is `evenList`, what is `oddList`, what is `integ`, you need to provide sample function calls and sample outputs for your question!

Comment: The answer is yes, since every iterative function can be replaced with a recursive one.

Comment: integ = 3    #number of sequences
evenList = ['GAAGCTCG', 'AAATTT', 'CTCTAGGAC']
oddList = ['CCTCGGGA', 'GGGCCC', 'GAGTACCTG']

Answer (score 0):

This does not fit in a comment so here a remark (not an answer). The code is quite redundant which makes things hard to identify. It's equivalent to:

```
integ = 3    #number of sequences
evenList = ['GAAGCTCG', 'AAATTT', 'CTCTAGGAC']
oddList = ['CCTCGGGA', 'GGGCCC', 'GAGTACCTG']

def matchList(evenList, oddList, integ):

        indexElement = 0
        indexList = 0
        totalIndexSeq = []
        at_List = ['AT', 'TA', 'at', 'ta']
        gc_List = ['GC', 'CG', 'gc', 'cg']

        for x in evenList:
            indexedSeq = ''

            for y in x:
                if y + oddList[indexList][indexElement] in gc_List + at_List:
                    indexedSeq += str(indexElement)                    
                else:
                    indexedSeq += "+"
                indexElement += 1

            indexList += 1
            indexElement -= indexElement
            totalIndexSeq.append(indexedSeq)

        return totalIndexSeq
        #This returns the positions with mismatched pairs omitted by a "+"
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done even simpler (is it about genetic coding on DNA?):

```
evenList = ['GAAGCTCG', 'AAATTT', 'CTCTAGGAC']
oddList = ['CCTCGGGA', 'GGGCCC', 'GAGTACCTG']

def matchList(evenList, oddList):

        totalIndexSeq = []
        match_list = [('A','T'), ('T','A') ,('G','C'), ('C','G')]
        pairedList=zip(evenList.upper(),oddList.upper()) # tuples from evenList and oddList elements
        for p in pairedList:
            pairs=zip(list(p[0]),list(p[1])) # tuples of even and odd list characters
            indexSeq=[ str(i) if p in match_list else '+' for i,p in enumerate(pairs)]
            totalIndexSeq.append(''.join(indexSeq)) #convert to string and add to list
        return totalIndexSeq
```

you don't have any limit on the length of the list (actually you didn't use `integ` in your code as well). Now you have to tell me which part you want to be recursive? 
I generally advise against recursion because of high resource usage.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much. I need to make the process of finding the matching pairs and appending those pairs to the 'totalIndexSeq' done through recursion rather than using a for-loop.

Comment: In other words, I need to make the inner loop recursive.

Comment: You mean something like this:
 
def find_total_index_seq(pairedList) ----------
      remove the first pair from the pairedList ------------ 
      find indexSeq for the first pair --------------
      return [indexSeq] + find_total_index_seq(pairedList)